# Is there a workflow for using an HDR image for an irradiance map?

Tags: ios, metal, hdrimages

For Metal on iOS is there a workflow for using an HDR image - .hdr or .exr format - for an irradiance map?

Comment: You could load an HDR file in RGBE format by converting its shared-exponent representation into that expected by one of Metal's pixel formats (such as `MTLPixelFormatRGB9E5Float` or `RGBA16Float`, both of which are filterable). From there, you'd just sample it and use it in your shader.

Comment: Cool beans. Thanks as always Warren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load an HDR file in RGBE format by converting its shared-exponent representation into one of Metal's pixel formats (such as MTLPixelFormatRGB9E5Float or RGBA16Float, both of which are filterable). From there, you'd just sample it and use it in your shader.

Comment: Warren, one issue. HRD files are r:g:b:e = 8:8:8:8 (32bit). The corresponding Metal pixel format is r:g:b:e = 9:9:9:5 (32bit). I am a bit unclear on how to handle this. My thought was to create a source texture in rgbe then use myTexture.makeTextureView(pixelFormat:) to convert to rgba16Float.

Comment: I think there will be some manual conversion necessary (i.e., convert from RGBE8888 to an intermediate 16-bpc or 32-bpc color for each pixel, then quantize back to RGBE9995, or just use the 16-bpc value directly with `RGBA16Float`). In particular, this conversion is not supported by Metal texture views or `vImageConvert_AnyToAny`, to the best of my knowledge.